Benthos Sql Query Issue
I am trying to insert a root array in a SQL Server database using a SQL query, but I am facing an error while retrieving data from the root array.
Here's the error I get:

ERROR: failed to send message to SQL: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface  @service=benthos label="" path=root.output.broker.outputs.0

My Benthos file looks like this:
input:
  generate:
    count: 1
    interval: 0s
    mapping: |
      root = {
        "individualIdentifier": "101",
        "memberships": [
          {
            "effectiveDate": "2023-01-01",
            "terminationDate": "2023-12-31",
            "areaGroup": "Area1",
            "product": {
              "healthCoverageType": {
                "code": "M"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "effectiveDate": "2023-02-01",
            "terminationDate": "2023-11-30",
            "areaGroup": "Area2",
            "product": {
              "healthCoverageType": {
                "code": "MC"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "effectiveDate": "2023-03-01",
            "terminationDate": "2023-10-31",
            "areaGroup": "Area3",
            "product": {
              "healthCoverageType": {
                "code": "M"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
pipeline:
  processors:
    - bloblang: |
        root.data = this.memberships.filter(m -> m.product.healthCoverageType.code == "M").map_each(m -> {
          "individualIdentifier": this.individualIdentifier,
          "membership": m
        })
    - bloblang: |
        root = if this.length() == 0 {
          [
            {
              "individualIdentifier": this.individualIdentifier,
              "membership": null
            }
          ]
        } else {
          this
        }
output:
  broker:
    pattern: fan_out
    outputs:
      - type: sql
        sql:
          driver: mssql
          data_source_name: "" # database details
          query: |
            INSERT INTO <table_name>
            (
            source_primary_key
            )
            VALUES (?);
          args_mapping: |
            root = this.data.map_each(item -> [
              item.individualIdentifier
])

I am expecting 2 records to be saved in database table as per the logic added. Can someone please help me with the same? Thanks

Hey Raghav, as mentioned on Slack, please switch from the deprecated sql output to sql_insert (or sql_raw) and try again. Also, please note that the bloblang processor is also deprecated and mapping should be used instead. They're functionally equivalent.

Thanks Mihai Todor for your prompt response. I got the solution to my problem which worked both with SQL and sql_insert. By the way same error did pop up with sql_insert. I found the fix and updated the logic accordingly.
